# Server Problems C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, client-server

i want to create a simple client-server chat in C#.
My problem is: when i try to connect the client to the server. I got this error:

```
Chat Server Started ....
Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument out of range.
Parameter name: size
   in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   in ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Visual Studio\Chat Client-Server\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 57
```

P.s I translated the error in english there can be errors.

Line 57: `networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);`

complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{

class Program

{

    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();



    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.7");

        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

        int counter = 0;



        serverSocket.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");

        counter = 0;

        while ((true))

        {

            counter += 1;

            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();



            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];

            string dataFromClient = null;



            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));



            clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);



            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);



            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");

            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();

            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);

        }



        clientSocket.Close();

        serverSocket.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("exit");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }



    public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)

    {

        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)

        {

            TcpClient broadcastSocket;

            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;

            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();

            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;



            if (flag == true)

            {

                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);

            }

            else

            {

                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

            }



            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);

            broadcastStream.Flush();

        }

    }  //end broadcast function

}//end Main class





public class handleClinet

{

    TcpClient clientSocket;

    string clNo;

    Hashtable clientsList;



    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)

    {

        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;

        this.clNo = clineNo;

        this.clientsList = cList;

        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);

        ctThread.Start();

    }



    private void doChat()

    {

        int requestCount = 0;

        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];

        string dataFromClient = null;

        Byte[] sendBytes = null;

        string serverResponse = null;

        string rCount = null;

        requestCount = 0;



        while ((true))

        {

            try

            {

                requestCount = requestCount + 1;

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

                Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);

                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);



                Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            }

        }//end while

    }//end doChat

} //end class handleClinet

}//end namespace
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

to

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 10025);
```

to match the size of the declared array.

Comment: Thank you, now I got a new error.
    System.InvalidOperationException: Operation not allowed on    unconnected sockets.
    in System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.GetStream()
    in ConsoleApplication1.handleClinet.doChat() in D:\Visual Studio\Chat Client-Server\Consoleapplication1\Program.cs:line 206

Comment: Line 206:  NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

P.s i changed also line 208 that was equal to line 57

Comment: You need to call Connect() on the clientSocket, before you call GetStream().

Comment: I added it, but:
                 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Request of connection forwarded  to an already connected socket
   in System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
   in ConsoleApplication1.handleClinet.doChat() in D:\Visual Studio\Chat Client-Server\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 205